# Add attribute to an element

Tags: java, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML to create XML messages. I want to create the following message:

```
<item>
  <carrier close="true">1234567</carrier>
</item>
```

I created this corresponding Java code:

```
@Root(name="item")
public class Item {
    @Attribute(name="close")
    @Path("carrier")
    boolean closeCarrier;

    @Element
    private String carrier;
}
```

but I get the error:

> Element 'carrier' is also a path name in class nl.example.Item

When I use `@Path("item/carrier")` it creates the following:

```
<item>
  <carrier close="true">1234567</carrier>
  <item>
      <carrier close="true" />
  </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best you map the structure with classes here.

The **`Item` class** creates the **wrapping** `<item>...</item>` element:

```
@Root(name="item")
public class Item
{
    @Element(name = "carrier", required = true)
    private Carrier carrier;

    // ...
}
```

The **`Carrier` class** holds the actual **values**:

```
@Root(name = "carrier")
public class Carrier
{
    @Text
    private int value;
    @Attribute(name = "close")
    private boolean close;

    // ...
}
```

This will create the correct XML.

If `Carrier` is not intended to be public, you can hide it by making it private or an inner class of `Item`.